# google drive "unable to sync" how to know programmatically?

Tags: google-api

What I have seen is that our company get "unable to sync" quite often, and this issue have been around for some months now. It's impossible to get any information from Google if this should be fixed or not..?
It looks like the issue is solved every time the Google Drive is restarted, but since none is actually monitoring this, this sync can be out of date quite some time.

Now we are actually thinking of creating an application that tries to see the status of Google Drive and force it to be restarted if the sync is having issues.

I have seen that it is possible to make Google Drive log to '%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Drive\sync_log.log', but then it has to be triggerd from GUI with 'shift-click on icon and select Diagnostics'. Is there another way to force Google Drive to log at startup?

This way we can maybe trace the log and if we see "Unable to sync" we shutdown the process and restart it again from another program.

Or are there any better solution, without any need for a person to manually do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by creating an application that sync this files between the cloud and harddrive by it self using their API instead.